# Error message populates when I try to use the readrds function to read rds files in local github repository folder

Tags: r

I'm able to use readrds to read rds files stored in regular local folders on my computer. But when I try to read copies of the same files in a local github repository folder, I get the following error message:

Error in gzfile(file, "rb") : cannot open the connection

Here's what my code looks like:

```
data_import.rds <- file.choose()
data <- readRDS("data_import.rds")
```

Again, this works fine with local folders created on my computer, but not with the local Github repository folder. I've tried copying files back and forth so the issue isn't with the files themselves.

I would appreciate help figuring this out.

Thanks!

Comment: with `file.choose()`, you're storing the location of your RDS file as a string into the object `data_import.rds`. Try `data <- readRDS(data_import.rds)` instead

Comment: Thank you so much! This helped. If you can, please post your comment as a solution so I can mark this as answered.